# Using the Facebook Graph API for posting a customized image on user's facebook wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

In my Facebook app the user can assemble a couple of small images to a larger image. Is it at all possible to post this image to the user's wall without posting it as a photo?
As far as I can see, the alternative would be to post a link to a web page that contains the og:image meta tag but this appears to be quite cumbersome since I'm dealing with a customized image.
Is there any another way to post the image to the wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with the picture property on the [post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object which worked. For some reason it didn't work when I tried it some weeks back.